# Slow switching between activity

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, xamarin.android, xamarin

I work on MWC.Android project and I build me own project but i have problem when i switch between the activity becouse its takes couple of seconds and GC start. The problem shows in all switch between the activity. All object list etc its clean maybe is problem in settings my project.

Deploy from Devices:

```
[AbsListView] unregisterIRListener() is called 
[AbsListView] onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
[AbsListView] unregisterIRListener() is called 
[AbsListView] unregisterIRListener() is called 
[AbsListView] unregisterIRListener() is called 
[AbsListView] unregisterIRListener() is called 
[AbsListView] unregisterIRListener() is called 
[Mono] GC_BRIDGE num-objects 60 num_hash_entries 70 sccs size 70 init 0.00ms df1 0.24ms sort 0.03ms dfs2 0.15ms setup-cb 0.09ms free-data 0.09ms user-cb 27.86ms clenanup 0.18ms links 21/21/19/1 dfs passes 260/149
[Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 5.55ms, total 5.68ms, bridge 28.47ms promoted 368K major 1344K los 0K
[Choreographer] Skipped 76 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[AbsListView] unregisterIRListener() is called 
[AbsListView] unregisterIRListener() is called 
[AbsListView] unregisterIRListener() is called 
[--------] OnResume called, app is ready to interact with the user
[AbsListView] unregisterIRListener() is called 
[Mono] The request to load the assembly System.Xml v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
[Mono] Unloading image System.Xml.dll [0x7cae81d8].
[Mono] GC_BRIDGE num-objects 202 num_hash_entries 8119 sccs size 8119 init 0.00ms df1 17.58ms sort 2.99ms dfs2 7.84ms setup-cb 1.01ms free-data 6.10ms user-cb 35.55ms clenanup 0.46ms links 9462/9462/7954/4 dfs passes 18022/17709
[Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 31.77ms, total 31.95ms, bridge 54.08ms promoted 864K major 2208K los 64K
[Mono] The request to load the assembly System v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
[Mono] Unloading image System.dll [0x7acf0768].
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #2
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #3
[AbsListView] unregisterIRListener() is called 
[Mono] The request to load the assembly Mono.Security v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
[Mono] Assembly Mono.Security[0x7b675248] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT failed to load AOT module Mono.Security.dll.so: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/CarCatalog.CarCatalog/lib/Mono.Security.dll.so" not found
[Mono] The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
[Mono] Unloading image mscorlib.dll [0x7c1195b8].
Loaded assembly: Mono.Security.dll [External]
[Mono] The request to load the assembly Mono.Security v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
[Mono] Unloading image Mono.Security.dll [0x7c9a7668].
[Mono] The request to load the assembly System v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
[Mono] Unloading image System.dll [0x7c9a7668].
[Mono] DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/libc.so'.
[Mono] DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/libc.so'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libc.so' ('/system/lib/libc.so').
[Mono] Searching for 'uname'.
[Mono] Probing 'uname'.
[Mono] Found as 'uname'.
[Mono] DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/libc.so'.
[Mono] DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/libc.so'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libc.so' ('/system/lib/libc.so').
[Mono] Searching for 'gettid'.
[Mono] Probing 'gettid'.
[Mono] Found as 'gettid'.
[Mono] GC_BRIDGE num-objects 18 num_hash_entries 24 sccs size 24 init 0.00ms df1 0.09ms sort 0.09ms dfs2 0.21ms setup-cb 0.00ms free-data 0.06ms user-cb 30.79ms clenanup 0.03ms links 9468/9468/7960/4 dfs passes 18070/17739
[Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 20.20ms, total 20.35ms, bridge 31.28ms promoted 1232K major 3440K los 256K
[AbsListView] onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
[AbsListView] unregisterIRListener() is called
```

Sample of my code :

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        //CMobApp.LogDebug("CARS OnCreate");
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // set our layout to be the home screen
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ContentLayout);

        //Top left menu btn
        tittle = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView1);
        selectCar = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView2);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (this.Assets, "fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf");

        tittle.SetTypeface (tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        selectCar.SetTypeface (tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        //spinnerText.SetTypeface (tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        //Find our controls
        carListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.CarList);
        makeSpinner = FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.MakeSpinner);
        modelSpinner = FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.ModelSpinner);
        versionSpinner = FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.VersionSpinner);
        //Nowy spinner: GENERACJA
        generationSpinner = FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.TypeSpinner);
        ImageButton favouriteButton = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.favouriteButton);
        //var gallery = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.gallery);
        //var menu = FindViewById<FlyOutContainer> (Resource.Id.FlyOutContainer);
        //var menuButton = FindViewById (Resource.Id.MenuButton);
        favouriteButton.Click += (sender, e) => {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.SetClass(this, typeof(FavoritesScreen));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);            // http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            StartActivity(intent);
        };


        generationSpinner.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        InitMakeSpinner ();

        InitModelSpinner ();

        InitVersionSpinner ();

        InitGenerationSpinner ();




        // wire up task click handler
        if (carListView != null) {
            carListView.ItemClick += (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) => {

                var carDetails = new Intent(this, typeof(CarDetailsScreen));
                carDetails.PutExtra("CarID", cars[e.Position].ID);
                StartActivity(carDetails);

            };
        }
    }


    //NEW Adding generation:
    void InitGenerationSpinner () {



        generationSpinner.Enabled = true; 
        generationSpinner.ItemSelected += (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e) => {
            selectedGeneration = generation [e.Position];
            RunOnUiThread (() => {
                UpdateGenerationSpinner();  

                UpdateCarList ();
                selectedGeneration = null;
            });
        };


    }



    void InitVersionSpinner () {
        //versionSpinner.Enabled = false;
        versionSpinner.ItemSelected += (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e) => {
            selectedVersion = versions [e.Position];
            RunOnUiThread (() =>  {
                UpdateCarList ();
                UpdateGenerationSpinner();
            });
        };
    }

    void InitModelSpinner ()
    {
        modelSpinner.Enabled = false;
        modelSpinner.ItemSelected += (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e) =>  {
            selectedModel = models [e.Position];
            RunOnUiThread (() =>  {
                UpdateVersionSpinner();
                UpdateCarList ();
            });
        };
    }



    void InitMakeSpinner ()
    {
        makes = MakeManager.GetMakes ();
        if (makes.Count != 0) {
            selectedMake = makes [2];
            ArrayAdapter<Make> makesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Make> (this, Resource.Layout.SpinnerText, makes);
            makesArrayAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource (Resource.Layout.row_spinner); 

            makeSpinner.Adapter = makesArrayAdapter;
            makeSpinner.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
            makeSpinner.SetSelection (2);
            makeSpinner.ItemSelected += (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e) => {
                selectedMake = makes [e.Position];              
                RunOnUiThread (() => {
                    UpdateModelSpinner ();
                    UpdateCarList ();
                });

            };
        } else {
            makeSpinner.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Invisible;
            Android.Util.Log.Info ("CarsScreen.cs", "MakeManager count 0");
        }
    }

    protected void UpdateCarList() {

        if (selectedModel!=null && selectedVersion!=null && selectedGeneration == null) {
            //cars.Clear ();
            cars = CMob.BL.Managers.CarManager.GetCars(selectedModel, selectedVersion);     

        } else if (selectedModel!=null && selectedVersion!=null && selectedGeneration!=null) {
            //cars.Clear ();
            cars = CMob.BL.Managers.CarManager.GetCars(selectedModel, selectedVersion,selectedGeneration);      

        } else if (selectedModel!=null) {
            //cars.Clear ();
            cars = CMob.BL.Managers.CarManager.GetCars(selectedModel);  

        } 
        else if (selectedMake!=null) {
            //cars.Clear ();
            cars = CMob.BL.Managers.CarManager.GetCars(selectedMake);
        } 
        else if(selectedGeneration!=null){
            //  cars.Clear ();
            cars = CMob.BL.Managers.CarManager.GetCars(selectedGeneration);
        }

        carListView.Adapter = new CMob.Adapters.CarListAdapter(this, cars); 



    }

    protected void UpdateModelSpinner() {       
        if (selectedMake != null) {

            models = ModelManager.GetModels(selectedMake);

            modelsArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Model> (this, Resource.Layout.SpinnerText , models);
            modelsArrayAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource (Resource.Layout.row_spinner); 
            modelSpinner.Adapter = modelsArrayAdapter;
            if (models.Count > 0) {
                modelSpinner.Enabled = true;
            } else {

                modelSpinner.Enabled = false;
            }

        }
    }

    protected void UpdateVersionSpinner() {     
        if (selectedModel !=  null) {

            versions = VersionGeneralManager.GetFilteredVersions((List<Car>)CMob.BL.Managers.CarManager.GetCars(selectedModel));
            ArrayAdapter<VersionGeneral> versionAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<VersionGeneral> (this, Resource.Layout.SpinnerText , versions);
            versionAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource (Resource.Layout.row_spinner); 
            versionSpinner.Adapter = versionAdapter;
            if(versions.Count>0) 
                versionSpinner.Enabled = true; 
            else 
                versionSpinner.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    //Generation spinner:

    protected void UpdateGenerationSpinner() {      
        if (selectedVersion !=  null) {

            generation = BL.Managers.GenerationManager.GetGenerations(selectedModel);

            ArrayAdapter<Generation> genAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Generation> (this, Resource.Layout.SpinnerText , generation);
            genAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource (Resource.Layout.row_spinner); 


            generationSpinner.Adapter = genAdapter;
            if (generation.Count > 0) {

                generationSpinner.Enabled = true; 
                generationSpinner.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

            }else {

                generationSpinner.Enabled = false; 
                generationSpinner.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

            }
    }
    }



    public int getMake(){
        return selectedMake.ID;
    }

    public string getMakeText(){
        return selectedMake.Makename;
    }

    public string getModelText(){
        return selectedModel.Modelname;
    }
    public string getGenerationText(){
        return selectedGeneration.Generationname;
    }
    public int getScreenType(){
        return 0;
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {   UpdateCarList ();
        Log.Debug ("--------", "OnResume called, app is ready to interact with the user");
        base.OnResume();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Nothing in the log you have posted indicates that anything is slow. If you sum up the ms it takes for the GC, it is less than half a second. You problem lies elsewhere and you need to provide more information on what exactly you are doing. Minimal code sample would be very helpful.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I create app Car Catalog on this screen i get all cars from datatabase and display list of cars in listview.

Comment: Well, there you have your answer then: you are synchronously loading  loads of stuff and that simply takes a while.